# Unable to pass javascript variables into Google Maps API

Tags: php, javascript, maps

I'm using the following code in a php file

```
  <script>      
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': '<?php echo $element['singleCoords']; ?>' },
              function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  firstLoc = results[0].geometry.location;
                  var gmap<?php echo $element['id']; ?>_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(firstLoc)
```

When I alert `firstLoc` the long and lat are displayed like: 5.34.., 5,6...

But when I used the variable `firstLoc` in the function `google.maps.LatLng()` I can see in the code explorer of Chrome that only the variable name is passed and not the long and lat numbers.

In the code explorer I see this:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(firstLoc)
```

but I want to see this:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(5.34.., 5,6...).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to set the position as a LatLng co-ordinate

According to [Google Maps doco](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat) you can just pass `results[0].geometry.location` into position